# Set time series for cross sectional data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to R and I need to conduct a time-series, cross-sectional (TSCS) analysis in R (dynamic probit). I know how to run the model, but I need to tell R that I am dealing with TSCS data.

I have data for 44 countries (countries are both coded numerically and in character form in the data set), and for 52 years for each of these. E.g:

```
Angola 1950
Angola 1951
.
.
.
Benin 1950
Benin 1951
```

I have found the `ts()` command, but I am not sure if I have used it correctly. My code so far is:

```
outdata50time <- ts(data=outdata50, start=1950, end=2002)
```

Will that do the trick? Or do I need different classes for the countries?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am confusing with your question. What do you expect to have? when you type head(outdata50time) what do you have?

Comment: if I type "head(outdata50time)" then I get
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA. I am used to tell the programme from years in STATA that I am using time series data. That is all I want to do. I just got confused with what exactly I have to provide in the the ts() command to properly set it as TSCS data.

Comment: The output I get from dput(outdata50) is huge and is not even fully displayed. I have 44 cross-sections, and 52 years of analysis. All I want to tell R now before running my dynamic probit model, is that I have time-series, cross-sectional data, that "year" is my time variable and that the "country number" is my cross section variable. Or do I not have to do that in R?

Answer (score 1):

Load the data set (I added some data points to the data set in the question):

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Angola", 
"Benin"), class = "factor"), Year = c(1950L, 1951L, 1950L, 1951L
), Data = c(23L, 24L, 45L, 64L)), .Names = c("Country", "Year", 
"Data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
```

Once you got this, I would create some sort of a loop to extract the data related to each country. An example for one country would be the following:

```
ts <- ts(test[Country=="Benin"]$Data, start=(1950), frequency=1)
ts
Time Series:
Start = 1950 
End = 1951 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 45 64
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the reply! The data goes up to year 2002 but that should be easily done. What do 1L, 2L, etc. stand for though? Sorry, as I said I am still new to R. Thanks again for your time! Much appreciated!

Comment: @FlorianReiche The `structure()` line the output of a function `dput`, which is used to include data in the text. This 1L is part of the syntax to encode that. What is more important is that you get a table that you are familiar with when you type `test`. The code just separates the values on the basis of the first column; make sure that the years are properly ordered.

Comment: Ok, great, I think I can complete the code now more or less for all 44 cross sections. One last question before I do that: What does the "Data = c(23L, 24L, 45L, 64L)" bit do? How would I have to change that for more than two countries? Similarly, how would I have to adjust the row.names? Thanks again!!!

Comment: The `structure` was really a shortcut for embedding data in this page. When working on my R installation I usually load the data with `read.csv`. This will load the data in a data.frame and then you can make a data.table out of it and filter it as I showed in the second block of code.